# ERC-20 token address on Rinkeby for testing

Tags: contract-debugging

I am looking for addresses of ERC-20 tokens on Rinkeby in order to test my smart contract. I know that I can find a lot of them at https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/.
However, it would be nicer if there are some that works as kind of reference for testing purposes, with lots of operations etc. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I have just created an ERC-20 token and verified its source code.

TokenERC20_Mock:0xc3994c5cbddf7ce38b8a2ec2830335fa8f3eea6a

It was created in this transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4b889d97e317a7de7bf30a08e5e61717877d034e75b751c07e3c4d0c0d990e08

It was tracked by EtherScan as a valid token: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xc3994c5cbddf7ce38b8a2ec2830335fa8f3eea6a

This symbol is TTW (Token for Tradeable Wallet)

I also veriied its source code, so you can read/write using EtherScan by using Read Contract/Write Contract functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to list all ERC20 transfers on Etherscan and explore what contracts are available by following this [link](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tokentxns). A contract I personally use more often that not is OpenZeppelin's [ERC20Mintable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Mintable.sol) because it lets you mint tokens on demand.

I deployed a toy ERC20Mintable contract here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x477369e951659c64259428e65142dbc321fd583c#code

Feel free to check out the source code, read and write to the contract.